# mysql does't release the lock even if the row does not match where clause

Tags: mysql, transactions

In mysql document https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html. It says

> SELECT ... FOR UPDATE and SELECT ... FOR SHARE statements that use a
> unique index acquire locks for scanned rows, and release the locks for
> rows that do not qualify for inclusion in the result set (for example,
> if they do not meet the criteria given in the WHERE clause).

But in practice, it does not work as I expected. Here is my test.

Create a new Table Person.

```
CREATE TABLE `Persion` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `age` bigint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `Persion_name_IDX` (`name`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Insert following data.

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | bob | 19 |
| 11 | cat | 20 |

This is my sql statement.

```
//transaction 1
start transaction;
SELECT  * from test.Persion p  where id IN (10,11) and age=19  for UPDATE;

//transaction 2
UPDATE test.Persion set name='tx6' where id=11;
```

In transaction 1, when I execute the `select...for update` sql, it should not lock the id=11 record, because it does't match the `age=19` condition. So my second transaction should not be blocked. But in fact, it is!

So I want to know what happend. Did I understand the document correct?

Answer (score 0):

I read the documentation the same way you do, and I think it's unclear or incorrect. I repeated your test and I got the same result you did — the row with id 11 remained locked by the first session.

Then I tested your case after setting the following in the first session:

```
SET transaction_isolation='READ-COMMITTED';
```

This allows the second session to update the row.

This makes me think locking follows the same rule for updates in READ-COMMITTED isolation level, described on this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html

> `READ COMMITTED`
>
> Using READ COMMITTED has additional effects:
>
> - For UPDATE or DELETE statements, InnoDB holds locks only for rows that it updates or deletes. Record locks for nonmatching rows are released after MySQL has evaluated the WHERE condition.